# Pointer casting with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

ARC is giving me a hard time with following cast:

```
NSDictionary *attributes;
SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainItemQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes);
```

Error: Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef *' (aka 'const void **') is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that attributes shouldn't be a dictionary, it should be a SecKeyRef or CFDataRef. And then cast that back into NSData for the password data copied into it.

Like so:

```
CFDataRef attributes;
SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainItemQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes);
NSData *passDat = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)attributes;
```

Comment: Small adjustment to make ik work: SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) keychainItemQuery,  ( CFTypeRef*) &attributes);

Comment: @mmvie I edited it to make it work.  Thanks for pointing out the minor error.

Comment: I disagree that "The problem is that the attributes shouldn't be a dictionary".  What is returned in the CFTypeRef is dependant on how the keychainItemQuery is constructed (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemCopyMatching).  If you change NSData to NSDictionary in your answer then that would also have fixed the error being raised.  Your fix works as the call to SecItemCopyMatching now uses a CFDataRef directly and the introduction of the __bridge_transfer.

Answer (score 6):

As we were doing something similar things and using the example above, we were facing another problem:

```
CFDataRef resultRef;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,
               (CFTypeRef *)&resultRef);
NSData* result = (__bridge_transfer NSData*)resultRef;
```

This will result in an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, because resultRef is not set to any adress and points somewhere to the memory.

```
CFDataRef resultRef = nil;
```

This will fix the error.

Comment: This happens specifically if your search is not found.

Comment: This happens **only** if the item is not found (because the `SecItemCopyMatching` does not initialize any data for its second argument, as there is not data to return). You should not need to do anything with `resultRef`if nothing was found (i.e. `status` is not `errSecSuccess`).

Answer (score 3):

Need to change `attributes` to `&attributes`

```
CFDataRef attributes;
SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) keychainItemQuery,  ( CFTypeRef*) &attributes);
NSData* passDat=(__bridge_transfer NSData*) attributes;
```