# Type conversion causing compilation error in ARC environment

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, type-conversion

I am having a problem in type conversion in ARC environment.If anyone would be kind enough to address it as well:

When i used this line of code:

```
NSData *resultData = nil;

NSMutableDictionary *passwordQuery = [query mutableCopy];

[passwordQuery setObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: (__bridge  id) kSecReturnData];

status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge  CFDictionaryRef) passwordQuery, (CFTypeRef *) &resultData);
```

Then i am recieving an error:

`Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective C pointer to 'CFTypeRef*'(aka 'const void **')is disallowed with ARC.`

Please suggest me any way to ressolve this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I ***Strongly*** (See, it's important, I used three *'s) suggest you read the official clang docs on ARC, it answers all this and more: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822892/pointer-casting-with-arc

Comment: Am not sure about the error, but I believe you are trying to use keychain here.Why dont you use this keychainwrapper class..?Its very easy to use. https://gist.github.com/1170641  or you can follow this tutorial, http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1  n see if you doing something wrong somewhere..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result data type is merely a `CFTypeRef` until after the call to `SecItemCopyMatching` so start by passing in a `CFTypeRef`:

```
CFTypeRef resultData = nil;
status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) passwordQuery,  &resultData);
```

Since the query specified that the `resultData` should be a `CFDataRef` the `resultData` is now a `CFDataRef`, and you can now cast it as such. then cast it further into an `NSData`.

```
CFDataRef resultCFData = (CFDataRef)resultData;
NSData *resultNSData = (__bridge NSData *)resultCFData;
```

Or in one line:

```
NSData *resultNSData = (__bridge NSData *)(CFDataRef)resultData;
```

Comment: the cast to `CFDataRef` can be skipped then; it is not doing anything there

Comment: user102008: As far as the compiler is concerned, that cast does nothing, and disappears in the compilation process. I leave it in merely as a reminder to any future programmers what's going on.